# Grant access to record by a lookup field

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing, sharing-rule

We want to grant access to opportunities based on a lookup field.

For example

We have an opportunity in our org.
I am the current owner.
There is a lookup field to users called Team member.

We need the team member to have access to the opportunity record.

Do I need a trigger for this?

Comment: you can use apex managed sharing

Comment: Why can't you just use [Opportunity Team Members](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesteam_def.htm&language=en&type=0)?